# Doctrine entity copy all fields to existing entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity class Post and it contains fields `id` and `old_id`, Because when user creates new post and save, another user can edit the same post and submit for review, but this second edit should not be effect on original post until it validate by original user and then when original user validates and approve this edited post it should merge/update original post. So I create those two fields to track one post is copy of another post so once the author approved second post I can update original post and discard duplicate.

I have managed to duplicate post with

```
public function __clone() {
   $this->id = null;
}
```

And copy with it.

```
// copying from old post
$new_post = clone $post;

// set original id
$new_post->setOriginalId($post->getId());

//save
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($new_post);
$em->flush();
```

everything is fine, but now when author aproving original post, how can i update the real post with data of duplicated post.

```
$original_post = $repository->find($new_post->getOriginaId());
//now i want to merge all $new_post datas to this $original_post
// and update $original_post
```

Comment: why not simply $original_post = $new_post; $original_post->setId($new_post->getOriginalId()); $original_post->setOriginalId(null); ?

Comment: entity doesnt have setId method, may be its due to security?

Comment: create an extra field which contains original id when copying to duplicate.
when its approved get origional id and update its(origional) status to pending and show the copy one.

Comment: Thanks this for the idea, it works.